# Creating a pop up window in GUI. C++

Tags: .net, visual-c++, user-interface

I've just started to use GUI, and I ran into a little problem.. What I want to do, is when I press "Assignment", I want a pop up window to appear that holds some text.

[Picture of the form. "Assignment" is in a menu strip.](http://prntscr.com/2z3r3m)

What should I do? I'm using Visual Studio 2013. Should I create a new MyForm.h and make it pop ip when I click "Assignment" or is there an easier and faster way?

Comment: `MessageBox::Show("Message", "Title");`  Depends on what you mean by popup.. `MessageBox` is the most basic of all..

Answer (score -2):

You'll want to start at looking at .net win forms

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235634(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Well, that doesn't explain how to add a pop up.. Those are the basicis that I have down already.